Processing OSNI .dwg to PostGIS
I'm processing the OSNI fusion dataset and it has been supplied in .dwg format - and I need to get it in to a PostGIS database. Any advice on the best way to do this?
The dataset is made up of 17,000 .dwg files and contain multiple geometry types and lots of feature types. I'm trying using FME but the best way I know how to use it is to create lots of shapefiles and then to process thoses to PostGIS. This doesn't seem very efficient also I don't want lots of shapefiles and tables in the database.

Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/39262958/1253336 ? If ogr2ogr can give you the geojsons or another format, it's fairly straightforward to import to postgis afterwards
